# No route to host (Host unreachable) while downloading files from ftp server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, amazon-web-services

I am trying to download files from FTP server, in the beginning the code was working properly, but all of a sudden this starting to failing in local machine & servers too..

Here is the FTP url and **PMC7258802.tar.gz** is file name

> ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/4e/da/PMC7258802.tar.gz

**ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov** is the base URL
Still same error **NOTE**: when i download from browser works fine, i have disabled the firewall too in ubuntu + Internet speed is also 90MPS

I have tried possible duplicate stack overflow questions too still no result

When tried from terminal :
[image]

tried to open the ports with but still same error:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=21/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Where as in AWS Ec2 (but asking for username/password):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS issue. I tried and it all worked for me.

Try to check that your DNS can resolve `ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov`.

You can try with the IP address instead of the name, to eliminate the DNS issue. The IP address is `165.112.9.228`

For authentication, the FTP server is accepting anonymous login (with some restrictions on what you can do). So try with `username: anonymous/ password:[any-email-address like test@test.com]`

[image]

Comment: They are clearly distributing (maybe roundrobin?) multiple IPv4 addresses because from different servers I get (after the CNAME) variously 165.112.9.229 165.112.9.230 130.14.250.7 130.14.250.13 which are close (but not equal) to both your value and the OP's.

Comment: Right, but any of these IP addresses should work.